# Convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence in $L^\infty$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite measure. It is well-known that, for a sequence $\left\lbrace f_n\right\rbrace _{n\in\mathbb N}\subset L^2(E)$,  convergence in $L^\infty(E)$ implies convergence in $L^2(E)$; however, convergence in $L^2(E)$ does not necessarily implies that of $L^\infty(E)$. The classic counterexample is the sequence $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ given by $f_n(x)=x^n$, $n\in\mathbb N$.

We can restrict ourselves to smaller families to circumvent this issue. Let E be now a compact subset of $\mathbb R$, and consider a family $\mathcal F$ of uniformly bounded and equicontinuous functions. For this family, convergence in $L^\infty(E)$ and convergence in $L^2(E)$ are equivalent, and moreover,  for all $\varepsilon$ there exists $\delta$  such that $|f|_{L^2(E)}<\delta$ implies $|f|_{L^\infty(E)}<\varepsilon$. If not, there would exists $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence $\left\lbrace f_n\right\rbrace _{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathcal F$ such that $|f_n|_{L^\infty(E)}>\varepsilon$ and $f_n\to 0$ in $L^2(E)$. But this cannot be because using Arzelá-Ascoli Theorem, we can extract a subsequence that converges uniformly to some $f^*$, but then this subsequence would converge to $f^*$ in $L^2(E)$, implying $f^*=0$ by the uniqueness of the limit in $L^2(E)$. A contradiction.

Thus, there exists a modulus of continuity, $\omega:[0,\infty]\to[0,\infty]$ such that $|f|_{L^\infty(E)}\le\omega(|f|_{L^2(E)})$ for all $f\in\mathcal F$, e.g.,
\begin{align}
\omega(\delta)=\sup\left\lbrace |f|_{L^\infty(E)}: f\in\mathcal F\quad\text{and}\quad |f|_{L^2(E)}\le\delta\right\rbrace.
\end{align}

The question is, what is the nature of these moduli of continuity ? Can one find at least a Holder modulus of continuity ?

What about for more general families of functions ? Are there families in which one can have a Holder modulus ? Is there a biggest family in which convergence in $L^2(E)$ and $L^\infty(E)$ are equivalent ?